# discord.pyでURL先のデータを保存する方法

Tags: python

URL先のデータを保存する方法が調べてもわかりませんでした。

urlwatchというものがあると助言いただいたのですがいまいちわかりません・・

教えてください。

discordのbotに関する質問なのですが・・・

-追記-
http://www3.nhk.or.jp/sokuho/jishin/data/JishinReport.xml

これを
保存
↓  ５秒後
サイトと先ほど保存したものを比べる
↓  変化あり-------------↓変化なし
メッセージを送信--------はじめに戻る
↓
上書き保存
↓
はじめに戻る

という動作を作りたいです。

わたしが想定ついている方法としましてはこのようなものです。

```
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    async def on_ready(self):
        while True:
            #URLを開く
            #中身を保存
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            #URLを開く
            #もしURL先のページと保存した内容が同じなら
                return
            #もし違うなら
                channel = self.get_channel(525064127056707585)
                await channel.send("test")
```

Comment: URL先のデータとは、何を指していますか？また、discord.pyやdiscordのタグを付けていますが、discordと関連するものでしょうか。

Comment: Q.URL先のデータとは、何を指していますか？
A.これは書き込みが不十分だったため追記します。

Comment: `discord.py`は主に「Discordとやり取りをする」為のモジュールです。一方で質問の中でやりたいことは「指定のwebサイトからXMLを取得する」で、Discordとは直接の関連が無い、より一般的なお話になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urllib` や `requests` を利用して対象のXMLを取得、ファイルのハッシュサムやXMLを解析した結果を保存しておき、定期的に取得して差分があるかどうか確認することで実現可能です。

データの保存については、ローカルにファイルとして保存する方法（ `tempfile` モジュールを使うと良いでしょう）や、解析した結果などをメモリ上に保存する方法があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

やってみます